# Why does the navigation bar change on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, firefox

I'm making a simple 4 page website, but on the [Portfolio page](http://cindyearlcovic.com/portfolio.html), the main navigation bar (like where you'd type in www.google.com) gets smaller when you click on this page.

If you click back and forth on the other pages, it expands and then it gets smaller again when you click on the portfolio page. It gives the appearance that the site is "jumping" around when you click on the portfolio page.

Any help? I've been trying to figure out this for HOURS.

[image]

Comment: What browser? I don't see anything like that in Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar Pinging you... the OP has updated with a screenie.

Answer (score 2):

It's because all of your other pages have a scrollbar and your Portfolio page doesn't; meaning there's a slight horizontal difference.

You can force all pages to show a scrollbar, using CSS:

```
body
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/urIZiTu/1).

Comment: I don't see a scrollbar on any page unless I make my browser window small.

Comment: That will be why. I'm viewing the site on a laptop @ 1,366 x 768.

Comment: thank you!! i tried that but it didnt change...this is my body css below, am i doing something wrong?

body {
 background-position: center top;
 font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: @GabrielleMusic I just checked your site. It's working! Your nav links are all in the same place across all pages `:)` Maybe try to force your browser to refresh. Press Ctrl + F5 on your Portfolio page.

Comment: I thought he was talking about the browser's address bar, not the navigation links.

Comment: @Barmar After re-reading the question, that appears to be the case. Hmm...

Comment: @GabrielleMusic Can you make a screenshot of your problem and upload to somewhere like [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)?

Comment: http://imgur.com/rUtMB3F

see where the red circles are? they arent lining up on the portfolio page. on all of the other pages, they line up... so when you click on the portfolio page it seems like the content is shifting from left to right.. like "jumping" - i HOPE this makes sense! :(

Comment: http://imgur.com/vHllxVS  this image might show the not lining up better

Comment: @GabrielleMusic I see your problem! It's bizarre! What browser is that? Safari?

Comment: no! firefox 23.0.1 and I'm on an iMac if that matters.. :(

Comment: @GabrielleMusic I can't reproduce the problem in Firefox 24.0 on Windows 7. Starting up my Mac now to see if I can reproduce it on there.

Comment: aww! thank you @DannyBeckett! I am taking a rest for the night, been looking at this computer for FOUR hours now trying to figure out this problem :(

Comment: @GabrielleMusic Before you do, try updating Firefox to v24.

Comment: I did.. no luck! It still is wonky

Comment: @GabrielleMusic Ah ok, worth a try. I'm installing Firefox on my Mac now. Hopefully will have some news for you when you get up tomorrow!

Comment: @GabrielleMusic Tested it on OS X 10.8.5 using Firefox 24.0 - no repro!

Comment: @GabrielleMusic http://i.stack.imgur.com/snCxj.png

Comment: @GabrielleMusic What version of OS X are you using? I presume you've rebooted and tried again?

Comment: I also can't reproduce. I'm on OS X 10.6.8. Try disabling all your add-ons, I'll bet it's related to one of them.